# ¿Datetime-Local a formato Y-m-d H:i:sP'?

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs, datetime, formato

Estoy trabajando sobre angular y estoy guardando la fecha de dos datetime-local con un ng-model

```
<input type="datetime-local" ng-model="column_Data.date_Start" placeholder="yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss" min="2014-01-01T00:00:00">
```

y luego lo estoy enviando por medio de http a el controlador para hacer una consulta que seleccion la fecha inicial y la fecha final de la consulta

```
$column_DB = DB::select("SELECT ".$Dato1." as dato, horaSistema FROM albatros_db2.".$Dato2." where horaSistema >= '".$date_Start."' and horaSistema <= '".$date_Finish."'");
```

el problema es que cuando recibo los datos con el ng-model me aparece con este formato

```
Fri Jun 02 2017 10:01:38 GMT-0500 (Hora est. PacÃ­fico)
```

no tengo la menor idea de porque me llega ese formato y como puedo cambiarlo a un formato mas manejable

**Actualización Controlador Angular**

```
//Se obtiene las columnas de cada tabla
$scope.getColumn = function ()
{
    $scope.dataservice.data_Modify = [];
    var num_Column = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.saveData.Column_Select.length; i++)
    {

        //Pedido a la ruta Reporte/consult_Report
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'consult_Report' + 2 + "," + $scope.saveData.Column_Select[i].column +","
            +$scope.saveData.Column_Select[i].table+","+$scope.saveData.Column_Select[i].date_Start+","
            +$scope.saveData.Column_Select[i].date_Finish+''
        })
            .then(function (response)
            {
                $scope.data_Final = new Object();
                var value_Column = [];
                var date_Column = [];
                //Se recorre el objeto y se guardan los datos
                for (i_Data = 0; i_Data < response.data.length; i_Data++)
                {
                    value_Column[i_Data] = response.data[i_Data].dato;
                    date_Column[i_Data] = response.data[i_Data].horaSistema;
                }


                $scope.data_Final.name = $scope.saveData.Column_Select[num_Column].column+"--"+$scope.saveData.Column_Select[num_Column].table;
                $scope.data_Final.values = value_Column;
                $scope.data_Final.date = date_Column;
                $scope.dataservice.data.push($scope.data_Final);
                $scope.dataservice.data_Modify.push($scope.data_Final);

                num_Column = num_Column + 1;
            });
    }
    translation_Menu(3);
};
```

Comment: Si agregas el código de tu controlador, va a ser más fácil darte una respuesta ya que el problema es que estas enviando por `$http` un objeto `date` en lugar de una cadena que represente la fecha en un formato específico.

Comment: @MarcosGallardo hablas del controlador de angular?

Comment: Si, del controlador angular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es la fecha por defecto en JavaScript si no me equivoco, y creo que es independiente del formato también.

En mi caso, uso una función como esta para convertirla:

```
function formatoFecha(fecha) {
    var d = new Date(fecha),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

    return [day, month, year].join('-');
}
```

Te dejo un ejemplo en plunker: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:CR2TtS1zz9wFGgsl5z2c?p=preview

Puedes quitar o agregar información en esa función para que el formato se corresponda a tus necesidades.

Espero que esto sea de utilidad. En caso contrario, no dudes en preguntar todas las veces que necesites.

Comment: Gracias, voy a serle algunas modificaciones para que se aplque como necesito pero me acabas de salvar la vida!!!

Gracias nuevamente

Comment: No hay de que estimado, saludos!

Comment: Te puedo preguntar algo, en tu codigo miras si tu mes es menor a 2
`if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;`

Para que haces esto?

Comment: En algunos navegadores puede dar error si tú mes es 3 en vez de 03 por ejemplo, por eso agrega un 0 a los meses del 1 al 9. El getMoth() devuelve un entero del 0 al 11, por eso también le suma 1 y lo convierte a string. Casi lo mismo con el día, pero no hace falta sumar. Saludos

Comment: Gracias por el codigo, me funciona bastante...